# How to set class variables in PHP?

Tags: php, class, private, setter

I have a class in php and want to know if there is a specific convention how to set these private variables in my constructor.

Should I set them with my `setter` or with `this`?

```
class foo {

  private $bar;

  public function __construct($foobar) {
     $this->bar = $foobar;
  }

  public function setBar($bar) {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }

  public function getBar() {
    return $this->bar;
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
class foo {

  private $bar;

  public function __construct($foobar) {
     $this->setBar($foobar);
  }

  public function setBar($bar) {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }

  public function getBar() {
    return $this->bar;
  }
}
```

Or is my question just philosophical? 
Same question could be asked with `getters`. But I guess you have to use `setters` and `getters` when handling private variables of your parent class.

Comment: Since your getter and setter literally do nothing but get/set the variable with no restrictions, you might as well make it `public` and modify it directly ;)

Comment: Good point. So you just use `setters` and `getters` only when you want to do something else beside just return them as they are?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I disagree. 1) Make everything a method for the object - saves on confusion 2) What happens in the future if one of them is to be calculated? See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176876/why-shouldnt-i-be-using-public-variables-in-my-java-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `setBar` in the constructor because of data validation, and future maintenance.

```
// a developer introduces a bug because the string has padding.
$foo->setBar("chickens   ");

// the developer fixes the bug by updating the setBar setter
public function setBar($bar) {
    $this->bar = trim($bar);
}

// the developer doesn't see this far away code
$f = new foo("chickens   ");
```

The developer sends the code to production thinking he fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

In such a trivial example, yes your question is mostly philosophical! :)
However, if your setter would perform some special actions (such like checking the validity of the input, or modifiying it), then I would recommend to use the second scheme.

Comment: That is a good point - so setter is a good place to validate the input?

Comment: Good point too! Well, by "input", I actually meant the argument of the function, not a user's input. Generally speaking, I prefer verifying the user's input separately. However, with some simple applications, you don't always want to follow all the best practices. Everything always depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  class foo {

  private $bar;

  public function __construct($foobar) {
     $this->bar = $foobar;
  }

  public function setBar($bar) {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }

  public function getBar() {
    return $this->bar;
  }
}
```

is no different than this:

class foo{

```
 public function __construct($bar){
     $this->bar = $bar;
 }

 public $bar;
```

One reason to use a getter and a setter is if you only allow a variable to be set on object construction like the following:

```
class foo {

  private $bar;

  public function __construct($foobar) {
     $this->bar = $foobar;
  }


  public function getBar() {
    return $this->bar;
  }
}
```

So don't overuse getters and setters unless necessary